# how get php respone from jquery .load

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

i give another codes for example 
this is my some3.php code:(First file)
:

```
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.7.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('p').click(function(){
        var who = $('input#who').val();
        var why = $('input#why').val();     
        $('#geting').load('file2.php',{who:who,why:why},function(applyData){
  if ( applyData == 'YEY . Ye have hi' ){
alert('OKKK data is ok ');
  } else{
      alert('Nooo We dont have requested output');
  }
        });
    });
});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> click </p>
<input type="text" id="who">
<br>
<input type="text" id="why">
<div id="geting" align="center">
</div>
</body>
```

i this my file2.php:

```
<?php
echo "1";
echo "2";
    if($_REQUEST['who'] == "hi"){


    $myVariable = "YEY . Ye have hi";
    echo $myVariable;
    } else{
   $myVariable = "The out put is not Hi";
    echo $myVariable;
    }
?>
```

its not work why? becuse we have echo "1" and echo "2"
i want jquery just check $myVariable data not whole php callback ! i think i must use json but i dont know how

Comment: What is the error? Why are you using `toString()`?

Comment: Are you Iranian? - As you are echoing a string there is no need to use `toString` method.

Comment: for example if i just put 1 more echo in file2.php its just do else{
      alert('ok');
this line ! what i must use in jquery for check just my $myVariable data in php output?

Comment: It seems what you want is JSON, you can create a key->value array in PHP and then `json_encode()` the result.

Comment: yes im iranian , so if i clean .toString() i can have more output in my file2.php?

Comment: can you give me example by json and my code?

Answer (score 2):

Well, assuming that you want to read the value with JQuery off the page you are posting to, you could do this, since you are echo'ing the value out in that page by doing the following: `echo $myVariable;` 
Now this is how I generally read a value off another page with JQuery which is by using JQuery's `get()` method.

```
$.get("thepagetoretrievefrom.php", function(retrievedvalue) {
    alert("Here's the data you requested: " + retrievedvalue);
    if (retrievedvalue == 1)  {
        //print out something here
        alert("The retrieved value was 1.");
    }
});
```

And that should retrieve the value from the PHP page. "thepagetoretrievefrom.php" is the page where you want to retrieve the information from. function(retrievedvalue) just indicates that whatever output you're requesting from the page via JQuery will be put into retrievedvalue. Then, using JQuery, you may decide whether you want to do a new call to another page depending on what the "retrievedvalue" was.
This, however is not the best method to achieve this, since this will print whatever may be in that page, but if you are requesting one specific value from that page, then it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: retrievedvalue this return what? a $retrievedvalue ? or all output from thepagetoretrievefrom.php?

Comment: It will output everything from thepagetoretrievefrom.php. If you want to retrieve a specific value, you would need to be more specific when doing the call, which is the easy way and that could be achieved by using the $_GET[] method in the page you're posting to, then you would send the value as thepagetoretrievefrom.php?myvalue=1
By using `$value = $_GET['myvalue'];` you could just echo that out as follows:
`if($value == 1) {
echo "The value is 1";
}`
And it would only echo that out to JQuery.
By only that, I'm saying that it would only echo: "The value is 1" as an alert this case.

Comment: i actully want jquery check a value from php like just check $myvariable value and not whole page and give a respone .... like i have this $a = 1 $b = 1 $c = 1 and echo $a echo $b echo $c but jquery just check $b value and give respone like if $b == 1 alert('ok') else alert('not ok') i hope gived a full detail about my request

Comment: Yes, you could achieve that with the example I gave you above your post. Since you're sending a specific value to that page first, then you're basically checking that value there with an if statement, and retrieving whatever is retrieved back from that page you sent the value to, to JQuery to then do whatever you require with it.