# Php: How to get textbox value from mysql database without submitting the form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, forms

I want to check the values from either one of the two textboxes text boxes that matches the value with the other without submitting the form. The keypress event is handling this, sending the value from jour_info.php page to get_sid.php page.
I have two files

1. jour_info.php
2. get_sid.php

The code in the first file

```
<form method="post" name="journ_form" >
P-ISSN/ISBN<br/><input name="printissn" id="printissn_input" type="text" value="">
                                            <input type="text" name="pissnsid" id="pissnsid" style="width: 30px;" autocomplete="off" value="">

                                            <span style="color: red;" id="feedback"></span>
 </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
$('#feedback').load('get_sid.php').show();

$('#printissn_input').keyup(function(){

    $.post('get_sid.php', {printissn: journ_form.printissn.value},
    function(result) {
        //$('#feedback').html(result).show();
        document.getElementById('pissnsid').value = result;
    }); 
});


$('#pissnsid').keyup(function(){
    $.post('get_sid.php', {pissnsid: journ_form.pissnsid.value},
    function(result) {
        document.getElementById('printissn_input').value = result;
    });
});
});
```

The code in the second file

```
<?php
 include 'auth.php';

 $printissn = $_POST['printissn'];
 $pissnsid = $_POST['pissnsid'];

 if($printissn){
$check = mysql_query("SELECT printissn, pissnsid FROM jour_entries WHERE   printissn='$printissn'");
$check_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)){
    //$get_printissn = $row['printissn'];
    $get_printissnsid = $row['pissnsid'];
    if($check_num_rows == 0){
        echo '';
    } else if($check_num_rows == 1){
        echo $get_printissnsid; 
    }
}
  } else if($pissnsid){
  $check = mysql_query("SELECT printissn, pissnsid FROM jour_entries WHERE pissnsid='$pissnsid'");
  $check_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($check);
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($check)){
$get_printissn = $row['printissn'];
//$get_printissnsid = $row['pissnsid'];
if($check_num_rows == 0){
    echo '';
} else if($check_num_rows == 1){
    echo $get_printissn;    
} 
 }
} 
?>
```

Now everything is working fine, the problem is when a value is entered in the first text box its showing the corresponding match in the second text box. But in case if the value doesn't match with the two fields and user needs to enter manually the data, the problem arises. When there is no match and user enters a value in first textbox, then the second textbox value disappears. How to solve that?

Comment: If what you're trying to do is gather a value by using JQuery and do something with it like print it out or compare it with another one, then here is something that may be of your interest: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058816/how-get-php-respone-from-jquery-load/13059086#13059086 `$.get()` is the answer for that in some of the cases.

Comment: How about you do not set the value if you have no value to set?

Comment: Yah if a person enters a value and it will show a match in the second textbox, if not match the person can enter the value manually in the second text box, but the problem is when we try to enter value in the second textbox the value in the first textbox disappears.

Comment: How to solve that, some condition wrong in some place.

Comment: Since you are already using jQuery, you could use it for assigning values as well - e.g. `$('#printissn_input').val();`.

Comment: Ok let me summarize the **problem** to make sure I understand it clearly. When someone enters a value in #printissn_input that is not matched in #pissnsid and modifies manually the value of #pissnsid, then #printissn_input becomes empty, is that right?

Comment: Yes bro you are right. Please help

Comment: Yes bro you are right. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

jour_info.php **changes**:

```
$('#pissnsid').keyup(function(){
    $.post('get_sid.php', {pissnsid: journ_form.pissnsid.value},

    function(result) {
        if('' != result)
            document.getElementById('printissn_input').value = result;
    });
});
```

Comment: What happens? Is is the same result? Do you get anything different at all? Do you have any error in the debugging console?

Comment: The problem is when i enter something in the textbox the text disappears in the other textbox how to solve that?

Comment: Not really. Do you get any console error? Did you try logging things on the PHP side? When you enter a text in #pissnsid that matches #printissn_input, what happens?

Comment: It matches shows the result in either textbox, but if not match and user wants to enter manually the data then it becomes empty, how to avoid that?