# Returning array from PHP to jQuery autocomplete isn't working.

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#tags').autocomplete({
source:function(request,response){
        $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         data: "",
         url: 'getplacetags.php',
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
            var resultSet = data;
            var arr=[];
            for(var i in resultSet)
            {
                arr.push(resultSet[i])
            }
            return arr;
    },
    error: function () {
        alert('failure');
    }
});
    }
});
});
</script>
```

html-:

```
<input type="text" id="tags" />
```

i have a problem in returning array to autocomplete function . the array arr is not showing in autocomplete in textbox why?

the json data is retrieved fine from getplacetags.php

Comment: Well, you're doing a post call but you're not sending any data. data: "" Maybe using $.get() to retrieve data is a better idea.

Comment: @ Ignacio Belhot Colistro-     what type of call should be done when you dont have any data to send?

Comment: I edited my comment above, @bhawin

Comment: @ Ignacio Belhot Colistro -  can i set type="get"?

Comment: see this link http://www.pontikis.net/blog/jquery-ui-autocomplete-step-by-step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use `return arr;` instead write

```
response(arr);
```

i.e. send your arr to the callback function you get in `response`

Comment: can you give some link to know about how request and response work

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't find any comprehensive example that uses `response`. The closest thing I could find is http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and I found that it is working fine after remove "contentType".

```
$('#tags').autocomplete({
    source:function(request,response){
        $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             data: "",
             url: 'http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON',
             dataType: "json",
             success: function (data) {
                 alert('success');
            },
            error: function () {    
                alert('failure');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Please check the working code here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Qy49d/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a very similar question:
[how get php respone from jquery .load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058816/how-get-php-respone-from-jquery-load/13059086)
If what you want to do is grab information from a page, without sending any data to it, then you can do the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get("getplacetags.php", function(retrievedinfo) {
    alert("Here's the data you requested: " + retrievedinfo);
    if (retrievedinfo)  {
        //Success
        //print out something here
    }
});
</script>
```

It's not a really clean way to solve the issue but it is way shorter.
Also, if you would like to show something in an element, like for example show an array, you should do the following:

**There are actually two ways that I know of:**

```
$("#yourElementID").html(retrievedinfo); //Where retrievedinfo would be your returned array.
```

**or**

```
$("#yourElementID").text(retrievedinfo); //Where retrievedinfo would be your returned array.
```

That way you can display what your function returned in a web element.